# Error importing JSON file in Parse

Tags: json, parse-platform, import, error-handling, format

My current file looks like this:

```
{
"result": [
  {
    "Longitude" : "-075.947332",
    "Zipcode" : "21922",
    "ZipClass" : "STANDARD",
    "County" : "CECIL",
    "City" : "ELKTON",
    "State" : "MD",
    "Latitude" : "+39.593612"
},
{
    "Longitude" : "-075.884544",
    "Zipcode" : "21930",
    "ZipClass" : "PO BOX ONLY",
    "County" : "CECIL",
    "City" : "GEORGETOWN",
    "State" : "MD",
    "Latitude" : "+39.366183"
  }
 ] 
}
```

I continuously get the following error:

> file should have the following format 
>   { "results": [ {...}, ... ]}

Any ideas whats going on or how I can import my file.
The link to my file is right here for further understanding: http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/MD&jsoncallback=?

Note* (There is no "?" in my JSON file like data in above link.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change "result" to "results".

The file you linked to begins with a parenthesis (`(`), that might be an issue too.

Comment: Removed the parenthesis and also changed result to results. Still not working :/

Comment: What I would try to do in your position is to start with the smallest file that works, and then start adding in your data until you encounter a problem.